# comparing dates is not working angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have to show all the events that its date >= to the current date.  I try this code in my html file:

```
<a class="item" ng-repeat="evt in events" ng-if=" evt.startdate >== sysDate" >
</a>
```

Sysdate is the current date :  `$scope.sysDate= new Date().toISOString() ;`

Bur i get this error message :

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '=' not a primary expression at column 18 of the expression [(evt.startdate >== sysDate) >
```

How can i fix it please ? ngularjs

Comment: You are missing parentheses in ng-if! You might even remove it all.

Comment: i rectify it but the same thing

Comment: use `>=` not `>==`

Answer (score 0):

Just a tought, mabye it's beter to do something like this :

    `<div ng-repeat="evt in events">
        <a ng-if="evt.startdate >== sysDate"> {{evt}}</a>
    </div>`

Is your evt.startdate of the same type as sysDate? 
mabye you shoudn't do the .toIsoString and compare 2 Date object with eachother.

And make a new key in the event as something like `evt.stringDate`.

Comment: when i log  startdate : i show this form : `"2016-05-08T05:59:00.000Z"`    and when logging sysDate i get this form : ` "2016-05-22T10:54:28.031Z"` So they are in the same  type

Comment: can you log typeOf(sysdate) and typeOf(evt.startDate). I dont think you can compare strings with the >= operator !